# Logistic Regression (or maybe a Hazard Model?) Question

Tags: regression, logistic

I am trying to predict the probability that a bankruptcy will end in a certain month. As a background, these bankruptcies last 60 months maximum. My Y variable will be 1 if the bankruptcy ended early and 0 if it did not. I have the date it started, the date it ended, and thus I can figure out how long before it ends in terms of months. How do I go about this?

Here's an example: The bankruptcy started on Jan 1, 2012. The bankruptcy ended on February 1, 2013. The bankruptcy should typically last 60 months but this one ended early. I need the probability it will end in month 1, 2, 3, ..., 60. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you have two questions. The first one is to predict whether a bankruptcy ends early, and the other to predict which month a bankruptcy will end in. For the latter question, for each bankrupt person, you wish to infer a conditional probability distribution with support on the months 1, 2, 3, ..., 60. If you have a lot of data, I would try and fit a quantile regression forest. This of course can then be used to answer the former question. However, if you are only interested in whether a bankruptcy ends early, then a logistic regression may be suitable.

Comment: Alex, I only have 850 observations. Do you think that's enough for a quantile regression forest?

Comment: Also, thanks for the input! You don't think a logistic regression would be good for saying "the probability of ending in month 1 is B1, the probability of ending in month 2 is 2B1, etc..."?